# Duplex WCF: host runs on desktop, interacts with website (client)?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I want to use Duplex WCF between the host (a desktop app) and a web site, where the web site is the client and the desktop app runs the WCF host.

> The user should click on a  button on the web site, it does an ajax call to an asmx web service which in turn should send the command to the host (which then talks to a bunch of other desktop apps; but I've learned how to do this last part from all the tutorials I found online)

I essentially want two interfaces: one between the host and a bunch of other desktop clients (which I already know how to do) and one between the host and a website, which at this point only needs to receive a message/command from the website (this is the part I need help on).

I've seen examples of Duplex WCF between the host and the client where the client is a desktop application (GUI), but not where the client is a website/web service.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use duplex ( with Callback) or client server architecture. But you will install the server in the desktop ( as a client) and the client will send message to the server in the desktop....You know it all depends as to what you want to accomplish

Comment: The simplest way is create a wcf service and host it in the desktop application. Then Create the client to the wcf service and install it where ever you want and then make a connection from the client to the wcf service.Simple as that

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess it reduces to: how to add a wcf service to my asp forms website and then how to add wcf to my app. Both of these I think i can find resources for. The last thing would be making the connection between them, but I'm guessing that's easy too; part of wcf

Comment: SignalR is a better framework to use if you want to push messages from server to client. Duplex WCF bindings still have too many restrictions.

Comment: @DanHunex, I've updated the question, maybe you have some insight?